# SQL Query booking date between from and to

Tags: mysql, sql

Looking for a sql query that return the data based on the from and to date.

Table :

```
id - int
carid int,
bookingStartDate - datetime
bookingEndDate - datetime
```

Here all the following query that i tried to test but all its get fail to retun the expected result

Example 1:

```
set @startdate='2019-12-21'
set @enddate='2019-12-22'

--Example 1
select  id,bookingStartDate,bookingEndDate from orders
where  
(bookingStartDate between @startdate  and @enddate
and bookingEndDate between @startdate and @enddate)


--Example 2
select  id,bookingStartDate,bookingEndDate from orders
where 
status=4 and 
(bookingStartDate >=@startdate and bookingEndDate <= @enddate)

--Example 3
select  id,bookingStartDate,bookingEndDate from orders
where 
(bookingStartDate <= @startdate  and bookingEndDate >= @startdate)
or 
(bookingStartDate <= @enddate and bookingEndDate >= @enddate)
```

The requirement is, To check list all available cars based on the from date and todate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the overlapping range problem, and your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT id, bookingStartDate, bookingEndDate
FROM orders
WHERE
    @startdate < bookingEndDate AND
    @enddate   > bookingStartDate;
```

This would find all available reservations which are able to contain the date range defined by `@startdate` to `@enddate`.